# Breaking Wordpress posts into sections

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for something similar to [Pagely MultiEdit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagely-multiedit/) but rather than breaking up pages into different sections I want to break up posts into multiple sections. Does anything exist that can do this?

Comment: did you use visual composer?

Comment: No, I built my theme from scratch and now for the sake of the people using my theme (it's for internal use) I need the posts to have separate sections that my users shouldn't have to worry about.